# Classification of unknown dataset into known categories

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a number of datasets where I have an array of x, y, z coordinates of the endpoints of segments. First and second point represents a segment, so does third, fourth and so on...

[image: x, y, z coordinates of points]

The above data represents just a part of dataset... The entire dataset is a lot bigger.

I am required to train my machine with several datasets like this, so that it can predict the category of any unknown dataset further... The test dataset will also be the same as the above.

I need help with the approach. Which algorithm or approach can I use here to classify any unknown dataset into these known categories?

Comment: Don't you have the classes of each row ?

Comment: No, the rows are just the x, y, z co-ordinates of the endpoint of the segments as explained in the question

Comment: Then do you know how many classes you want ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate how should I make classes and how will that help? Will be really helpful if you tell that... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Its an unsupervised learning problem. If you know roughly in how many classes your data should be split use K-Means (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

Otherwise, a combination of TSNE (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) and Kmeans usually works well. Basically transform data using TSNE and run Kmeans in transformed data.